# Custom SOAP webservice response

Tags: apex, soap-api, webservices, xml

I have this scenario, an App using a Salesforce instance have to change and use another Salesforce Instance but only url for the webservice and credentials can be modified in the App. New custom SOAP service have to behave like the standard one, to achieve this we have to map the fields from the original Salesforce within the fields in the new Salesforce instance (this is done and working) but I have a problem trying to customize the SOAP Webservice response.

These are the requirements:

- I can not do any modifications in the app, only new Salesforce SOAP url, username and password.
- Queries must keep the same with the field names from the original Salesforce instance, this means I can not change the queries in the app.
- Expecting same result when a query is executed, field names, number of fields, etc.

Standard SOAP response (Original Salesforce instance):

- query: SELECT Id, Name, Subindustry__c FROM Account

```
//...
<soapenv:Body>
      <queryResponse>
         <result>
            <done>true</done>
            <queryLocator xsi:nil="true"/>
            <records xsi:type="sf:Account">
               <sf:Id>001100000000000001</sf:Id>
               <sf:Name>test 01</sf:Name>
               <sf:Subindustry__c>Subindustry 01</sf:Subindustry__c>
            </records>
            <size>1</size>
         </result>
      </queryResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
//...
```

Solution implemented so far:

I've created a class with a WebService method that handle this queries and a custom metadata to map the original fields to our current fields, e.g.: Original org field called **Subindustry__c**, new org **Channel__c**.

the method is working fine and I am able to replace the original fields with the new ones and get the list of records:

```
//...
webService static String query(String query){
        list<SObject> records = new List<SObject>();
        QueryProcessResponse processedQuery;
        try {
            processedQuery = replaceQueryFields(query);
            Database.QueryLocator queryLocator = Database.getQueryLocator(processedQuery.processedQuery);
            Database.QueryLocatorIterator iterator = queryLocator.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                records.add(iterator.next());
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            //Exception handle
        }
      return getXmlResponse(records, processedQuery.objectName);
}
private static QueryProcessResponse replaceQueryFields (String query){
//...
}
private static String getXmlResponse(List<SObject> records, String objectName){
//HERE IS MY PROBLEM
}
class QueryProcessResponse{
    public String objectName {get; set;}
    public String processedQuery {get; set;}
    public List<String> fields {get; set;}
}
```

- At first I tried to return a `List<SObject>` but I can not customize this response to match the standard one, at least I could not find anything I am open to suggestions.
- I am using now **XmlStreamWriter** to return a String that match the expected result but when I use SoapUI to test it, I get the string encoded and that is:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/SoapQueryReplicationWebservice">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <queryResponse>
         <result><![CDATA[
         <records xsi:type="sf:Account">
             <sf:Id></sf:Id>
             <sf:Name></sf:Name>
             <sf:Subindustry__c></sf:Subindustry__c>
         </records>         
         <size>1</size>]]></result>
      </queryResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

XML above is a how SoapUI display it, in raw mode you see the encode values like `&gt;` or `&lt;`

I used **XmlStreamWriter.writeCharacters()** and **XmlStreamWriter.writeCData()** with similar results, I also tried to replace the encode characters before returning the String  `result.replaceAll('&gt;','<');...`, this didn't work neither.

I have this question, do anyone have to do something similar to this? customizing the response from a SOAP WebService or any ideas how to avoid the characters encoding?

Thanks in advance and I am open to suggestions.

Comment: Step 1: learn about and use [Partner WSDL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_partner.htm). Step 2: [query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_query.htm) via SOAP on the Account object. This will return the data structure you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your reply at the end we are trying to solve using a REST service with XML, https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_rest_methods.htm, and with XmlStreamWriter to replicate the response.